# Get request info from HTTP response in node

Tags: node.js, httpresponse

It is possible, in a node.js application, to get any information about the HTTP request from the response itself?

Comment: What kind of thing are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the request url. It is not possible to store the request url after sending request so i am trying this way.

Comment: So, you are making a request, getting the response, and trying to figure out where the original request went to?  I don't think this is possible; HTTP doesn't return information about the original request back to the caller that made it, likely assuming you (as the caller) should already know what you asked for.